# text-align:center won't work with form <label> tag (?)

Tags: html, css

I was going through a site I have just completed, and fixing up some accessibility issues. 
I had a form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thank-you.php" />
<p>Enter your Email Address to receive our Weekly Newsletter</p>                            
<input name="email" type="text" id="formifemail" size="21" />
<input type="image" src="images/newsletter_button.jpg" alt="submit button" border="0" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Send" />
```

This was flagged because their is no  tag to identify the input field for entering the email address. So I changed the

tag to a  tag like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thank-you.php" />
<label for="formifemail">Enter your Email Address to receive our Weekly Research</label>                            
<input name="email" type="text" id="formifemail" size="21" />
<input type="image" src="images/newsletter_button.jpg" alt="submit button" border="0" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Send" />
```

and the CSS:

```
#formItem label {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:150%;
    font-size:.85em;
}
```

But the text appears as left justified, and not centered. I've looked around that there are no obvious bugs. This is happening in both FF 3.x and IE 7.x

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This is because `label` is an inline element, and is therefore only as big as the text it contains.

The possible is to display your `label` as a block element like this:

```
#formItem label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: .85em;
}
```

However, if you want to use the label on the same line with other elements, you either need to set `display: inline-block;` and give it an explicit width (which doesn't work on most browsers), or you need to wrap it inside a `div` and do the alignment in the `div`.

Comment: Also be aware that if you set width:100% - padding or margin on the right hand site wont work when the label is inside a table cell.

Answer (score 7):

`label` is an inline element so its width is equal to the width of the text it contains.  The browser is actually displaying the label with `text-align:center` but since the label is only as wide as the text you don't notice.

The best thing to do is to apply a specific width to the `label` that is greater than the width of the content - this will give you the results you want.

Answer (score 3):

`label` is an inline element so its width is equal to the width of the text it contains. The browser is actually displaying the label with `text-align:center` but since the label is only as wide as the text you don't notice.
Put it inside a `div` and give properties to the `div`.

```html
<div  style ="text-align:center;">
<label >Enter your Email Address to receive our Weekly Newsletter</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution
This is the code :
label {
display: inline-flex
align-items : center
justify-content: center
}
It works for me and I think it will be the solution for you problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It might be worth having a read of the formatting guide (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to help make posts that include code more readable. There's also some quick buttons in the editor to turn something into a "code block" so it looks nicer. I hope you enjoy your time here :)